# Connect GPS sensor to controller wirelessly

Tags: android-studio, arduino, gps

Hello I was wondering if you guys can point me in the direction regarding a project. I was planning on implementing a project using TinyGPS, arduino and android studio. This is an article i was using as reference: http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygps/

I understand the idea of connecting the GPS sensor to a controller (arduino) and then connect the controller to the computer or phone/app.

However all the references I am looking at show the sensor connecting to the controller with wired connection. I was wondering if there is a way to connect a GPS Sensor wirelessly to the controller(arduino)? I want to do this so i can "tag" an item with the GPS sensor and then track it with an application.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect the GPS with the GPS and Arduino serial ports. Connect the TX from GPS to RX on Arduino and RX from GPS to TX on Arduino.

I hope that helps.